# Slope of Line tangent

Tags: calculus

The slope of the line tangent to the curve implicitly defined by $$y^2+(1-xy)^3=0$$ at $(2,1)$ is?

$a)\ -\frac{3}{2}$

$b)\ -\frac{3}{4}$

$c)\ \ \ \ \ \  0$

$d)\ \ \ \ \  \frac{3}{4}$

$e)\ \ \ \ \ \frac{3}{2}$

Help please!!

Comment: Do you have some ideas?

Comment: try to differentiate the equation first..then you can do the rest..

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the slope of the graph will be given by the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$: AKA $\frac {dy}{dx}$.

To get that derivative from this implicitly defined function, we use -- you guessed it -- implicit differentiation!:

$$y^2+(1-xy)^3=0$$
$$\implies \frac d{dx}(y^2+(1-xy)^3)=\frac d{dx}0$$
$$\frac d{dx}(y^2)+\frac d{dx}[(1-xy)^3]=0$$
$$ 2y\frac {dy}{dx}+3(1-xy)^2\left[\frac d{dx}(1-xy)\right]=0$$
$$2y\frac {dy}{dx}+3(1-xy)^2\left[0-(y+x\frac {dy}{dx})\right]=0$$

Now solve for $\frac {dy}{dx}$ and plug in your point.

Answer (score 0):

Try to differentiate on the left hand side and make $\frac{dy}{dx}$ the subject of the equation.This is a very big hint which would lead you to the answer .Please don't post homework questions here next time.

Comment: Giving the answer (which I haven't verified) does nothing to discourage this kind of behavior.

Comment: @SimonS I removed it but when the questioner doesn't have enough idea about Math SE I thought let me give her time to learn how things get done here.